# How to call a function from a class binded to an element with the id of this element?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Kalendae/0.7.1/kalendae.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Kalendae/0.7.1/kalendae.standalone.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            alert("toto");
        document.getElementById("testKal").draw(); // i want to activate the draw function of auto-kal
    }
</script>

<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/hz8nrhh0yosvpgy/calendar.png?dl=1" id="imgTest" onclick="myFunction()">&nbsp;<input type="text" class="auto-kal" id="testKal">
</body>
</html>
```

I want that when i click on the calendar picture , the calendar of the input text pop.

It's the function draw of kalendae.

I've also tried to activate the click() function of testKal when the image is clicked  :

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Kalendae/0.7.1/kalendae.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Kalendae/0.7.1/kalendae.standalone.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            alert("toto");
        document.getElementById("testKal").click(); // i want to activate the draw function of auto-kal
    }
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle with the draw function :

https://jsfiddle.net/bussiere/wfj7bk3m/6/

And one with trying to pass the click :

https://jsfiddle.net/bussiere/6hdsL1n8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger focus event of input

```
document.getElementById("testKal").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("testKal").focus();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/56jnr937/